# Populate a hash with an array of keys and a default value in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have to write a method like so:

```
def populate_hash([key1, key2, key3], default_value)
  #
end

populate_hash([:apples, :oranges, :melons], 6) # { apples: 6, oranges: 6, melons: 6 }
```

If I was writing a method that was passing in two separate arrays (one for keys, one for values) it would be easy, but I'm unsure how to handle the default value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the code is not much different from what you mention. Try this:

```
def populate_hash(a, default_value)
  result = {}
  a.each{|k| result[k] = default_value}
  return result
end
```

I have not added any checks to verify that `a` is and Array, but it is quite easy to do so.

Comment: How would I add a check?

Comment: Add logic to do something if a is not an Array. You should be able to do that

Comment: That does indeed work.  Yes, I just figured out how to check, with a.kind_of? Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Another way that might work is to use `Array#product`:

```
def populate_hash(array, default_value)
  Hash[array.product([default_value])]
end
```

If you are using Ruby 2.1+, you could use `Array#to_h` as well:

```
def populate_hash(array, default_value)
  array.product([default_value]).to_h
end
```